# When a camera error occurs as a result of a lens error, is that a problem with the lens or the camera?

Tags: error, tamron, nikon-d80

I have a Nikon D80 and a Tamron 18-250MM lens. Every once and awhile, but often enough to be annoying, the camera will give the "Err" display. I've been able to determine that this is caused by slight movement of the connection between the lens and the camera.

Is this issue likely caused by the camera or the lens?  Is there anything that can be done about it?  Is this a common issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of thing *shouldn't* be common, and may be the sign of the contacts being at the extremes of "normal" tolerances, causing the communication issues between the lens and the body.

If you don't have the same problems with other lenses, and the Tamron is new; it may be worth going back to the dealer and getting them to test the lens on some other bodies and replace if the problems are reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

This sort of thing is not uncommon. It sounds like a communication failure between the camera/lens which is often resolved by cleaning the contacts. This may help in your case, however since you seem to be able to cause the problem by moving the lens slightly the problem may be minor damage to the lens or mount.

I'm afraid there no way to tell if it's the camera or the lens without trying a different lens on your camera, or trying your lens on a different camera body! If you don't know anyone with a Nikon lens you can borrow, you could try going to a camera shop and ask to try out a lens.

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to your question, but just in case any Canon users happen to be reading it...

The Canon 50D had a problem with "Err 99" appearing. Allegedly, this was due to poor-quality gold in the contacts on some lenses causing timing issues. While this sounds far-fetched to me, a firmware upgrade (more tolerant with timing issues?) fixed the problem.